# Add Swipe Support for Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, touch, swipe

I currently have a bootstrap tab pane with two different tabs. Is it possible to support swipe gestures on devices with touch screens to switch between the tabs? I found tons of libraries for carousels but nothing for tabs.

Answer (score 19):

1. Go to http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/, in Events
   select Touch. Press "Build my download". Download archive.
2. Add jquery.mobile.custom.min.js from downloaded archive to you javascript folder. Now we have support for *touchstart, touchmove, touchend, tap, taphold, swipe, swipeleft, swiperight, scrollstart, scrollstop* events.
3. Your html:

   ```
   <script src="jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script>

   <script>
       $(function() {
           $(".tab-content").swiperight(function() {
               var $tab = $('#tablist .active').prev();
               if ($tab.length > 0)
                   $tab.find('a').tab('show');
           });
           $(".tab-content").swipeleft(function() {
               var $tab = $('#tablist .active').next();
               if ($tab.length > 0)
                   $tab.find('a').tab('show');
           });
       });
   </script>

   <div role="tabpanel">

     <!-- Nav tabs -->
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="tablist">
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
     </ul>

     <!-- Tab panes -->
     <div class="tab-content">
       <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
       <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
     </div>

   </div>
   ```